# several csv files into one xlsx with multiple tabs in r?

Tags: r, excel, csv, xlsx

I have 3 separate csv files right now, and I want to combine these 3 into a single master excel spreadsheet with 3 tabs/sheets - each tab for each .csv  - **without** using xlsx package. Is this possible in R?

Comment: which packages can be used?

Answer (score 3):

Here's using the `writexl` package. You create a list where the name of the element will be the name of the sheet, and the object will be what will be on the sheet. So "sheet1" will contain `dat1`, which will be the data from your first csv file.

```
library(writexl)

out <- list("sheet1" = dat1, "sheet2" = dat2, "sheet3" = dat3)
write_xlsx(out, "output.xlsx")
```